# What is the natural lifespan of a human in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

Assuming you're not a Stormtrooper, **what is the natural lifespan of a human in the *Star Wars* galaxy?**

Comment: Related, if not dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18959

Comment: In the _entire_ galaxy?? There must be hundreds of billions of people on thousands of planets.

Comment: Just the mean? Is the standard deviation going to be a separate question?

Comment: @Mithrandir related indeed, but not a dupe as none of the answers mentions human lifespan 

Comment: @user14111 don't tempt me lol 

Comment: @Daft my understanding was that there is only the one actual species of humans; is this incorrect?

Comment: @N_Soong as far as I know yes. But such a vast, vast sample with so many variables, any answer will realistically provide no useful information.

Comment: But I suppose that's not really a reason not to ask a question.

Comment: We could look for old humans - possibly exclude Jedi/Sith - and extrapolate based on our own lifespans...

Comment: the average lifespan on Jakku is probably much lower than other places; the average lifespan on Hosnian Prime just dropped dramatically... this is a *really* broad question.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I take your point; would it be better to ask what the natural lifespan was for humans?

Comment: Canon - Dunno. [EU - Pushing 110](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Nest_I:_The_Joiner_King); "“Don’t be ridiculous,” Leia said. *“You’re barely in your mid-sixties.” “That’s my point,” Han said. “Just because a guy goes a little gray at the temples, people think he’s slowing down. They think they can push him around-“ “Han, nobody thinks you’re slowing down.” Leia’s voice grew soft. “You have at least forty good years left. Maybe even fifty, if you take care of yourself.”"*

Comment: @Richard excellent find; I'd be willing to accept that as an answer!

Comment: Pfft. EU rubbish. If someone wants to post it, they're welcome

Comment: @Richard better than nothing!

Comment: Less than 900 years.

Comment: @N_Soong life expectancy depends on the quality of life. There is no natural base lifespan unless you define the natural living conditions first. Stone Age homo sapiens live until their early 20s. Few reach the ripe old age of 30s. Likewise, a human from Naboo can probably expect to live longer than a human from Tatooine. As for the Force, extensive use of the neutral Force has restorative effects on your youth, while drawing on the dark side causes you to wither away.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Going by JUST Episodes I - VII, we have Obi-Wan Kenobi as one example. Now, granted, Obi-Wan Kenobi lived the first part of his life well-nourished and physically fit as a Jedi Knight, but also put under more extreme situations than the average human being would presumably undergo.

In Episode I, [Obi-Wan was 25 years old](https://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000004/bio). Though, the exact wording that they used was "a quarter century" in the *Phantom Menace* novel, so he's 25 standard galactic years old. Judging from his appearance and the descriptions used, he's about the same as a 25-year-old male in our galaxy a long time later and far, far away.

Episode II takes place ~10 years later, making him ~35 years old

Episode III takes place ~3 years later, making him ~38 years old

Episode IV takes place ~19/20 years later, making him ~58 years old.

> This is also the age where he dies by unnatural means.

At that point, people refer to him as "Old Ben" and "old fossil", so he's presumably in his latter years by typical human standards of the galaxy. Now according to this [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12269/62443), Obi-Wan seemed to age more quickly after the events of Episode III/his life on Tatooine. So he was ~58, but we'll say he appears to be ~60/65 years old.

[Humans in our galaxy living in the United States are given a life expectancy of ~78.8 years](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/life-expectancy.htm). At around the 50-year mark is when they're considered 'over the hill' and in their 'golden years' by the time they near 60.  In Episode IV, Obi-Wan was considered to be at about a similar level. So it would be a reasonable to conclude that humans (at least, Jedi humans?) in the Star Wars galaxy also have a natural lifespan of ~78.8 years.

Comment: Obi-wan's age is presented very inconsistently. There's also the possibility that he's been using the Force continually for 18 years, something  that would result in rapid aging

Comment: _At around the 50-year mark is when they're considered 'over the hill'_

Oh, that burns.

Answer (score 6):

### Canon

According to Lucasfilm Exec Leland Chee, the typical lifespan of a human in the Star Wars galaxy is almost exactly the same as that of a human on Earth (e.g. 70ish years).

> **Q.** **What is the average life-span of a human in Star Wars canon?**
>
> **LC:** *Similar to real-world. Was easier to say they lived longer in Legends
> because we didn't have to account for actors getting older.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://web.archive.org/web/20190722080534/https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/783493608989003776)</sup></sub>

This makes sense because humans in the Star Wars galaxy are ["anatomically identical"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/165774/20774) to Earth humans.

---

### Legends

Sources vary, but it's either around 100 years of age according to the [*Star Wars RPG Core Rulebook*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Roleplaying_Game_Revised_Core_Rulebook)

> **Physical Description:** Humans average about 1.8 meters tall. Skin shades run from nearly black to very pale, hair from black to blond.
> Men are usually taller and heavier than women. **Humans achieve maturity
> about the age of 15 and rarely live beyond 100.**

or up to 120 years of age (and over 200 for Force Sensitives and Jedi) according to the [*The New Essential Guide to Alien Species*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Alien_Species)

> **Humans can typically live up to a hundred twenty standard years**,
> though there have been isolated reports of **human Jedi living as many
> as two hundred.**